# Calling same function on two jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to execute the same code on two jQuery objects.

```
var a = $('.one_div');

.... more code ...

var b = $('.ban');

.... more code ...

a+b .hide('fast');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
a.add(b).hide('fast');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
$('.one_div , .ban').hide('fast');
```

If you want to use the same logic on cached variables then `.add()` is the way to go.